# Performance of Computing CRC

Tags: c++, performance, crc

```
#include "windows.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

unsigned long   crc32_table[]   = {
    0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xEE0E612C, 0x990951BA, 0x076DC419, 
    0x706AF48F, 0xE963A535, 0x9E6495A3, 0x0EDB8832, 0x79DCB8A4, 
    0xE0D5E91E, 0x97D2D988, 0x09B64C2B, 0x7EB17CBD, 0xE7B82D07, 
    0x90BF1D91, 0x1DB71064, 0x6AB020F2, 0xF3B97148, 0x84BE41DE, 
    0x1ADAD47D, 0x6DDDE4EB, 0xF4D4B551, 0x83D385C7, 0x136C9856, 
    0x646BA8C0, 0xFD62F97A, 0x8A65C9EC, 0x14015C4F, 0x63066CD9, 
    0xFA0F3D63, 0x8D080DF5, 0x3B6E20C8, 0x4C69105E, 0xD56041E4, 
    0xA2677172, 0x3C03E4D1, 0x4B04D447, 0xD20D85FD, 0xA50AB56B, 
    0x35B5A8FA, 0x42B2986C, 0xDBBBC9D6, 0xACBCF940, 0x32D86CE3, 
    0x45DF5C75, 0xDCD60DCF, 0xABD13D59, 0x26D930AC, 0x51DE003A, 
    0xC8D75180, 0xBFD06116, 0x21B4F4B5, 0x56B3C423, 0xCFBA9599, 
    0xB8BDA50F, 0x2802B89E, 0x5F058808, 0xC60CD9B2, 0xB10BE924, 
    0x2F6F7C87, 0x58684C11, 0xC1611DAB, 0xB6662D3D, 0x76DC4190, 
    0x01DB7106, 0x98D220BC, 0xEFD5102A, 0x71B18589, 0x06B6B51F, 
    0x9FBFE4A5, 0xE8B8D433, 0x7807C9A2, 0x0F00F934, 0x9609A88E, 
    0xE10E9818, 0x7F6A0DBB, 0x086D3D2D, 0x91646C97, 0xE6635C01, 
    0x6B6B51F4, 0x1C6C6162, 0x856530D8, 0xF262004E, 0x6C0695ED, 
    0x1B01A57B, 0x8208F4C1, 0xF50FC457, 0x65B0D9C6, 0x12B7E950, 
    0x8BBEB8EA, 0xFCB9887C, 0x62DD1DDF, 0x15DA2D49, 0x8CD37CF3, 
    0xFBD44C65, 0x4DB26158, 0x3AB551CE, 0xA3BC0074, 0xD4BB30E2, 
    0x4ADFA541, 0x3DD895D7, 0xA4D1C46D, 0xD3D6F4FB, 0x4369E96A, 
    0x346ED9FC, 0xAD678846, 0xDA60B8D0, 0x44042D73, 0x33031DE5, 
    0xAA0A4C5F, 0xDD0D7CC9, 0x5005713C, 0x270241AA, 0xBE0B1010, 
    0xC90C2086, 0x5768B525, 0x206F85B3, 0xB966D409, 0xCE61E49F, 
    0x5EDEF90E, 0x29D9C998, 0xB0D09822, 0xC7D7A8B4, 0x59B33D17, 
    0x2EB40D81, 0xB7BD5C3B, 0xC0BA6CAD, 0xEDB88320, 0x9ABFB3B6, 
    0x03B6E20C, 0x74B1D29A, 0xEAD54739, 0x9DD277AF, 0x04DB2615, 
    0x73DC1683, 0xE3630B12, 0x94643B84, 0x0D6D6A3E, 0x7A6A5AA8, 
    0xE40ECF0B, 0x9309FF9D, 0x0A00AE27, 0x7D079EB1, 0xF00F9344, 
    0x8708A3D2, 0x1E01F268, 0x6906C2FE, 0xF762575D, 0x806567CB, 
    0x196C3671, 0x6E6B06E7, 0xFED41B76, 0x89D32BE0, 0x10DA7A5A, 
    0x67DD4ACC, 0xF9B9DF6F, 0x8EBEEFF9, 0x17B7BE43, 0x60B08ED5, 
    0xD6D6A3E8, 0xA1D1937E, 0x38D8C2C4, 0x4FDFF252, 0xD1BB67F1, 
    0xA6BC5767, 0x3FB506DD, 0x48B2364B, 0xD80D2BDA, 0xAF0A1B4C, 
    0x36034AF6, 0x41047A60, 0xDF60EFC3, 0xA867DF55, 0x316E8EEF, 
    0x4669BE79, 0xCB61B38C, 0xBC66831A, 0x256FD2A0, 0x5268E236, 
    0xCC0C7795, 0xBB0B4703, 0x220216B9, 0x5505262F, 0xC5BA3BBE, 
    0xB2BD0B28, 0x2BB45A92, 0x5CB36A04, 0xC2D7FFA7, 0xB5D0CF31, 
    0x2CD99E8B, 0x5BDEAE1D, 0x9B64C2B0, 0xEC63F226, 0x756AA39C, 
    0x026D930A, 0x9C0906A9, 0xEB0E363F, 0x72076785, 0x05005713, 
    0x95BF4A82, 0xE2B87A14, 0x7BB12BAE, 0x0CB61B38, 0x92D28E9B, 
    0xE5D5BE0D, 0x7CDCEFB7, 0x0BDBDF21, 0x86D3D2D4, 0xF1D4E242, 
    0x68DDB3F8, 0x1FDA836E, 0x81BE16CD, 0xF6B9265B, 0x6FB077E1, 
    0x18B74777, 0x88085AE6, 0xFF0F6A70, 0x66063BCA, 0x11010B5C, 
    0x8F659EFF, 0xF862AE69, 0x616BFFD3, 0x166CCF45, 0xA00AE278, 
    0xD70DD2EE, 0x4E048354, 0x3903B3C2, 0xA7672661, 0xD06016F7, 
    0x4969474D, 0x3E6E77DB, 0xAED16A4A, 0xD9D65ADC, 0x40DF0B66, 
    0x37D83BF0, 0xA9BCAE53, 0xDEBB9EC5, 0x47B2CF7F, 0x30B5FFE9, 
    0xBDBDF21C, 0xCABAC28A, 0x53B39330, 0x24B4A3A6, 0xBAD03605, 
    0xCDD70693, 0x54DE5729, 0x23D967BF, 0xB3667A2E, 0xC4614AB8, 
    0x5D681B02, 0x2A6F2B94, 0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 
    0x2D02EF8D
};

unsigned long   repeat  = 0;
unsigned long GetCRC(const std::string& strFilepath)
{
    unsigned long   crc = 0;
    FILE*           fp  = NULL;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, strFilepath.c_str(), "rb") == 0 && fp != NULL)
    {   
        crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;

        char    c[ 655360 ];
        int size;
        while ( size = fread(&c, 1, sizeof(c), fp) )
        {
            ++repeat;
            std::cout << repeat << std::endl;
            for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            {
                crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[(crc ^ c[i]) & 0xFF];
            }
        }

        crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;

        fclose(fp);
    }

    return crc;
}

#include <mmsystem.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD t0, t1;
    unsigned long crc;

    t0 = timeGetTime();
    crc = GetCRC(argv[1]);
    t1 = timeGetTime();
    printf( "CRC : %X, time : %f sec\n", crc, (t1-t0)/1000.0f );

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting CRC value using above code. My problem is that its difference is too big. If I test 1GB file, first time, it took about **90 seconds** and second time, it took about **3 seconds**. I think there may be something like cache. At first time, hard-disk-read-LED was **ON** and at second time, the LED was **not ON**. After some seconds later, it took about 90 seconds again.

How this can be happen such a wide range of difference?

I'm using Windows XP Professional with Service Pack 3 and Core2(2.6GHz) with 2GB of RAM. Before I test, I terminated most of my application except some file explorer and Putty(terminal client). CPU usage was almost zero and PF usage was about 1GB.

Comment: And..., if I change the size of array c(in GetCRC function), just same result. :(

Comment: not of major importance but you could use `char c[ 655366 ];` so clusters can fit exactly to your buffer.

Comment: You could use Microsoft specific `_mm_crc32_u32` function if your processor supports SSE4. It will increase performance significantly.

Comment: @Kirill; Since the program spends 96.6% of the time waiting for the disk, I see no point in further optimizing the calculations. Even if you cut down the time needed for those to 10%, the program will still take 88 seconds to compute the CRC for a 1GB file. What's the point of that?

Comment: @xopht: If you remove the reference to `std::cout`, turn the `std::string' parameter into a `const char*`, remove the two corresponding includes, and add the one necessary for C IO (`<stdio.h>` for a C program), you have turned your pretty smelly C++ program into a quite nice C program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the OS (and maybe even the drive) *caches* the file. Upon first access it's read into memory, upon further accesses it's served from memory. You should never include the first access to a file into measurement, except when you want to measure disk access.

BTW, this also means that your program spends the overwhelming amount of its time waiting for IO. So there's hardly any reason to further optimize it - except if you find a way to optimize IO.

Comment: Then, can every bytes of the file - it's almost 1GB - can be cached? And one more. On another computer, there was no such a big difference between tests and pretty fast(about 5 seconds). Is this normal?

Comment: @xopht: I'd suspect the OS to take as much advantage of free RAM as it can. If you have 1GB free, I think the OS would use this. Whether the different results are "normal" (whatever that means) is hard to say. FWIW, on my machine it also takes 3sec (had a 0.99GB file laying around here), so the 90sec for the first run on the your other machine's result is probably due to a rather slow disk.

Comment: BTW, removing the `std::cout` from the loop gained almost 10% speedup for me. Console output is really slow on Windows.

Comment: std::cout in GetCRC() function is just for checking the speed - you can guess how much time does it take to read several bytes from the file. The point is not optimizing the function. It is why same code make such a big difference of result.